Do I need a visa if I am traveling from US to India (Indian passport) and have an 8.5 hour layover in Dubai airport (DXB)?
I do not care to go out of the airport to explore. I'll stay put for as long as I'm in the airport. My flight is from Boston to Bengaluru via Dubai and New Delhi. (My F1 visa will have expired by the time of the flight, but I do have a valid Indian passport, valid for three more years)

Context: "The transit visa is only issued to individuals whose stop at Dubai’s airports lasts more than 8 hours and less than 96 hours. Individuals whose connecting flight is between 2 to 8 hours of landing in Dubai [do not need one].", "Transit visas are available for all passport holders, from 48 to 96 hours. [..] Passengers must have a valid onward flight booking outside of the UAE and a valid hotel booking for the duration of the stay in the country. You will need to show copies of these bookings." https://www.visitdubai.com/en/plan-your-trip/visa-information

What airline are you flying with? Might be worth contacting them, as they can help you with the visa if you need one.

Thank you, @deceze
